# Why does the columns.render option in DataTables stop working with multiple columns?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using DataTables [Server Side](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) to generate a paginated MySQL table on my website.

I am using the [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to add a hyperlink to one of the MySQL columns like so:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "includes/pull_2.php",
                "columns": [
                    {
                       "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return "<a href=" + full[0] + ">" + full[0] +"</a>"; }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

This works perfectly if I only have one column in my table. For example:

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

However, as soon as I add another column to the array and another `<th>` to the table, the table stops rendering the table at all and just says "processing".

This is the table I am working on: http://clients.serallo.co.uk/formtest/

Does anybody have a suggestion as to why this does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of elements in `columns` array must match number of columns in the table.

You can use `columnDefs` option instead and target specific column. For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": "includes/pull_2.php",
   "columnsDefs": [
      {
         "targets": 0,
         "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
             return "<a href=" + full[0] + ">" + full[0] +"</a>"; 
         }
      }
   ]
});
```